# is there way access specific line in file (without looping) java - libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi i am using LibGDX to program android.

Is there some way to sraightforward access specific line on the file without going through all the lines and reading them until i reach desired line? (Can I just say I want to read line number so-and-so?)

I know there are such methods:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("list.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file.reader());
reader.readLine();   <--- but it reads only first line !
//// or using scanner
scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
scanner1.nextLine();   <--- also reads first line ..
```

Can I do it without looping through unnecessary lines? Any solutions, workarounds welcome. Thanx

Comment: For direct access, use a database table, instead.

Comment: btw not sure scanner would work straight in android anyway

Comment: You can use `java.io.RandomAccessFile`

Comment: Don't use "Scanner".

Comment: @Der Golem thanks 4 comment, could you give some link to some example or tutorial please?

Comment: No: this is not the place where to ask for tutorials. I can suggest you googling for `android sqlite crud`

Comment: @Der Golem aa sqlite yep, but I wanted this libGDX code to be available for other platfom, like iOS,  not sure if sqlite will work 4 that

Comment: iOS uses SQLite too. You can even use SQLite with VB.NET or C#.