# How to get direct access to specific record in file with SQLite? in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, sqlite, libgdx

I am programming Android using LibGDX.

I have big file and want to sraightforward access specific line on the file without going through all the lines and iterating them until i reach desired line.

I was 
[suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940276/is-there-way-access-specific-line-in-file-without-looping-java-libgdx?noredirect=1#comment46135558_28940276)
 to use SQLite for this.

So I followed [example](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite) and did this:

```
DatabaseCursor cursor;
cursor = mydb1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM comments");
 while (cursor.next()) {
            cursor.getString(1);
        }
```

Well it works , but that *is* iteration (looping)!  how to do it directly?
thanx

Comment: Add a **WHERE** clause which lets you specify a search criterion (or more than one). So you can return **only the matching record(s)**. I don't see the reason for posting another question, while you could edit your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940276/is-there-way-access-specific-line-in-file-without-looping-java-libgdx).

Comment: @DerGolem thanks, it worked! Thanks. Reason behind separate question -  this asks how to achieve this specificly with SQLite. Though an edit was possible.

Answer (score 1):

as advised did this and it worked:

```
cursor = mydb1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment='test recorddd'  ");
```